# Fatal Error: alsa/asoundlib.h: No such file or directory

Tags: javascript, node.js, heroku, npm

While trying to deploy my app on Heroku, I encountered an error as stated in the title: `Fatal error: alsa/soundlib.h: No such file or directory`

I don't know why this package is troubling me in the first place 'cause i didn't install it and i can't figure out which of my dependencies is depending on it. Anyway, does anyone have idea of how to fix it?

Here is my package.json:

```js
{
  "name": "audio-manager",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "start": "nodemon server.js",
    "dev": "next dev",
    "build": "next build",
    "next-start": "next start",
    "ngrok-start": "ngrok http 3000"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": "12.x"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "@shopify/app-bridge-react": "^1.26.2",
    "@shopify/koa-shopify-auth": "^3.1.65",
    "@shopify/koa-shopify-graphql-proxy": "^4.0.1",
    "@zeit/next-css": "^1.0.1",
    "apollo-boost": "^0.4.9",
    "crypto": "^1.0.1",
    "dotenv": "^8.2.0",
    "generate-sound-waveform": "^0.1.11",
    "graphql": "^15.3.0",
    "js-cookie": "^2.2.1",
    "koa": "^2.13.0",
    "koa-body": "^4.2.0",
    "koa-router": "^9.1.0",
    "koa-session": "^6.0.0",
    "next": "^9.4.4",
    "querystring": "^0.2.0",
    "react": "^16.13.1",
    "react-dom": "^16.13.1",
    "safe-compare": "^1.1.4",
    "webpack": "^4.44.0"
  }
}
```

I already ran the command: `sudo apt-get install libasound2-dev` and it installed, but anytime i run `npm install` it shows this message in the console:

```
npm install 
npm WARN deprecated crypto@1.0.1: This package is no longer supported. It's now a built-in Node module. If you've depended on crypto, you should switch to the one that's built-in.
npm WARN deprecated mkdirp@0.5.3: Legacy versions of mkdirp are no longer supported. Please update to mkdirp 1.x. (Note that the API surface has changed to use Promises in 1.x.)
npm WARN deprecated chokidar@2.1.8: Chokidar 2 will break on node v14+. Upgrade to chokidar 3 with 15x less dependencies.
npm WARN deprecated fsevents@1.2.13: fsevents 1 will break on node v14+ and could be using insecure binaries. Upgrade to fsevents 2.
npm WARN deprecated coffee-script@1.7.1: CoffeeScript on NPM has moved to "coffeescript" (no hyphen)
npm WARN deprecated resolve-url@0.2.1: https://github.com/lydell/resolve-url#deprecated
npm WARN deprecated urix@0.1.0: Please see https://github.com/lydell/urix#deprecated
npm WARN deprecated mkdirp@0.3.5: Legacy versions of mkdirp are no longer supported. Please update to mkdirp 1.x. (Note that the API surface has changed to use Promises in 1.x.)

> speaker@0.3.1 install /home/israel/Documents/sound-wave-image-generator/node_modules/speaker
> node-gyp rebuild

make: Entering directory '/home/israel/Documents/sound-wave-image-generator/node_modules/speaker/build'
  CC(target) Release/obj.target/output/deps/mpg123/src/output/alsa.o
../deps/mpg123/src/output/alsa.c: In function ‘initialize_device’:
../deps/mpg123/src/output/alsa.c:78:16: warning: comparison of integer expressions of different signedness: ‘int’ and ‘long unsigned int’ [-Wsign-compare]
   78 |  for (i = 0; i < NUM_FORMATS; ++i) {
      |                ^
../deps/mpg123/src/output/alsa.c: In function ‘get_formats_alsa’:
../deps/mpg123/src/output/alsa.c:201:16: warning: comparison of integer expressions of different signedness: ‘int’ and ‘long unsigned int’ [-Wsign-compare]
  201 |  for (i = 0; i < NUM_FORMATS; ++i) {
      |                ^
  AR(target) Release/obj.target/deps/mpg123/liboutput.a
  COPY Release/liboutput.a
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/binding/src/binding.o
In file included from ../src/node_pointer.h:6,
                 from ../src/binding.cc:5:
../../nan/nan.h: In function ‘void Nan::AsyncQueueWorker(Nan::AsyncWorker*)’:
../../nan/nan.h:2294:62: warning: cast between incompatible function types from ‘void (*)(uv_work_t*)’ {aka ‘void (*)(uv_work_s*)’} to ‘uv_after_work_cb’ {aka ‘void (*)(uv_work_s*, int)’} [-Wcast-function-type]
 2294 |     , reinterpret_cast<uv_after_work_cb>(AsyncExecuteComplete)
      |                                                              ^
../src/binding.cc: In function ‘Nan::NAN_METHOD_RETURN_TYPE {anonymous}::Open(Nan::NAN_METHOD_ARGS_TYPE)’:
../src/binding.cc:30:38: error: no matching function for call to ‘v8::Value::Int32Value()’
   30 |   ao->channels = info[1]->Int32Value(); /* channels */
      |                                      ^
In file included from /home/israel/.cache/node-gyp/12.18.3/include/node/node.h:67,
                 from ../../nan/nan.h:56,
                 from ../src/node_pointer.h:6,
                 from ../src/binding.cc:5:
/home/israel/.cache/node-gyp/12.18.3/include/node/v8.h:2709:40: note: candidate: ‘v8::Maybe<int> v8::Value::Int32Value(v8::Local<v8::Context>) const’
 2709 |   V8_WARN_UNUSED_RESULT Maybe<int32_t> Int32Value(Local<Context> context) const;
      |                                        ^~~~~~~~~~
/home/israel/.cache/node-gyp/12.18.3/include/node/v8.h:2709:40: note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 0 provided
../src/binding.cc:31:34: error: no matching function for call to ‘v8::Value::Int32Value()’
   31 |   ao->rate = info[2]->Int32Value(); /* sample rate */
      |                                  ^
In file included from /home/israel/.cache/node-gyp/12.18.3/include/node/node.h:67,
                 from ../../nan/nan.h:56,
                 from ../src/node_pointer.h:6,
                 from ../src/binding.cc:5:
/home/israel/.cache/node-gyp/12.18.3/include/node/v8.h:2709:40: note: candidate: ‘v8::Maybe<int> v8::Value::Int32Value(v8::Local<v8::Context>) const’
 2709 |   V8_WARN_UNUSED_RESULT Maybe<int32_t> Int32Value(Local<Context> context) const;
      |                                        ^~~~~~~~~~
/home/israel/.cache/node-gyp/12.18.3/include/node/v8.h:2709:40: note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 0 provided
../src/binding.cc:32:36: error: no matching function for call to ‘v8::Value::Int32Value()’
   32 |   ao->format = info[3]->Int32Value(); /* MPG123_ENC_* format */
      |                                    ^
In file included from /home/israel/.cache/node-gyp/12.18.3/include/node/node.h:67,
                 from ../../nan/nan.h:56,
                 from ../src/node_pointer.h:6,
                 from ../src/binding.cc:5:
/home/israel/.cache/node-gyp/12.18.3/include/node/v8.h:2709:40: note: candidate: ‘v8::Maybe<int> v8::Value::Int32Value(v8::Local<v8::Context>) const’
 2709 |   V8_WARN_UNUSED_RESULT Maybe<int32_t> Int32Value(Local<Context> context) const;
      |                                        ^~~~~~~~~~
/home/israel/.cache/node-gyp/12.18.3/include/node/v8.h:2709:40: note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 0 provided
../src/binding.cc: In function ‘Nan::NAN_METHOD_RETURN_TYPE {anonymous}::Write(Nan::NAN_METHOD_ARGS_TYPE)’:
../src/binding.cc:51:33: error: no matching function for call to ‘v8::Value::Int32Value()’
   51 |   int len = info[2]->Int32Value();
      |                                 ^
In file included from /home/israel/.cache/node-gyp/12.18.3/include/node/node.h:67,
                 from ../../nan/nan.h:56,
                 from ../src/node_pointer.h:6,
                 from ../src/binding.cc:5:
/home/israel/.cache/node-gyp/12.18.3/include/node/v8.h:2709:40: note: candidate: ‘v8::Maybe<int> v8::Value::Int32Value(v8::Local<v8::Context>) const’
 2709 |   V8_WARN_UNUSED_RESULT Maybe<int32_t> Int32Value(Local<Context> context) const;
      |                                        ^~~~~~~~~~
/home/israel/.cache/node-gyp/12.18.3/include/node/v8.h:2709:40: note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 0 provided
../src/binding.cc:62:78: warning: cast between incompatible function types from ‘void (*)(uv_work_t*)’ {aka ‘void (*)(uv_work_s*)’} to ‘uv_after_work_cb’ {aka ‘void (*)(uv_work_s*, int)’} [-Wcast-function-type]
   62 |   uv_queue_work(uv_default_loop(), &req->req, write_async, (uv_after_work_cb)write_after);
      |                                                                              ^~~~~~~~~~~
../src/binding.cc: In function ‘void {anonymous}::write_after(uv_work_t*)’:
../src/binding.cc:80:31: warning: ‘v8::Local<v8::Value> Nan::Callback::Call(int, v8::Local<v8::Value>*) const’ is deprecated [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
   80 |   wreq->callback->Call(1, argv);
      |                               ^
In file included from ../src/node_pointer.h:6,
                 from ../src/binding.cc:5:
../../nan/nan.h:1742:3: note: declared here
 1742 |   Call(int argc, v8::Local<v8::Value> argv[]) const {
      |   ^~~~
../src/binding.cc: At global scope:
../src/binding.cc:104:17: error: variable or field ‘Initialize’ declared void
  104 | void Initialize(Handle<Object> target) {
      |                 ^~~~~~
../src/binding.cc:104:17: error: ‘Handle’ was not declared in this scope
../src/binding.cc:104:30: error: expected primary-expression before ‘>’ token
  104 | void Initialize(Handle<Object> target) {
      |                              ^
../src/binding.cc:104:32: error: ‘target’ was not declared in this scope
  104 | void Initialize(Handle<Object> target) {
      |                                ^~~~~~
In file included from ../../nan/nan.h:56,
                 from ../src/node_pointer.h:6,
                 from ../src/binding.cc:5:
../src/binding.cc:155:22: error: ‘Initialize’ was not declared in this scope
  155 | NODE_MODULE(binding, Initialize)
      |                      ^~~~~~~~~~
/home/israel/.cache/node-gyp/12.18.3/include/node/node.h:608:36: note: in definition of macro ‘NODE_MODULE_X’
  608 |       (node::addon_register_func) (regfunc),                          \
      |                                    ^~~~~~~
../src/binding.cc:155:1: note: in expansion of macro ‘NODE_MODULE’
  155 | NODE_MODULE(binding, Initialize)
      | ^~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from ../src/node_pointer.h:6,
                 from ../src/binding.cc:5:
../src/binding.cc:93:12: warning: ‘Nan::NAN_METHOD_RETURN_TYPE {anonymous}::Close(Nan::NAN_METHOD_ARGS_TYPE)’ defined but not used [-Wunused-function]
   93 | NAN_METHOD(Close) {
      |            ^~~~~
../../nan/nan.h:1568:33: note: in definition of macro ‘NAN_METHOD’
 1568 |     Nan::NAN_METHOD_RETURN_TYPE name(Nan::NAN_METHOD_ARGS_TYPE info)
      |                                 ^~~~
../src/binding.cc:85:12: warning: ‘Nan::NAN_METHOD_RETURN_TYPE {anonymous}::Flush(Nan::NAN_METHOD_ARGS_TYPE)’ defined but not used [-Wunused-function]
   85 | NAN_METHOD(Flush) {
      |            ^~~~~
../../nan/nan.h:1568:33: note: in definition of macro ‘NAN_METHOD’
 1568 |     Nan::NAN_METHOD_RETURN_TYPE name(Nan::NAN_METHOD_ARGS_TYPE info)
      |                                 ^~~~
../src/binding.cc:47:12: warning: ‘Nan::NAN_METHOD_RETURN_TYPE {anonymous}::Write(Nan::NAN_METHOD_ARGS_TYPE)’ defined but not used [-Wunused-function]
   47 | NAN_METHOD(Write) {
      |            ^~~~~
../../nan/nan.h:1568:33: note: in definition of macro ‘NAN_METHOD’
 1568 |     Nan::NAN_METHOD_RETURN_TYPE name(Nan::NAN_METHOD_ARGS_TYPE info)
      |                                 ^~~~
../src/binding.cc:24:12: warning: ‘Nan::NAN_METHOD_RETURN_TYPE {anonymous}::Open(Nan::NAN_METHOD_ARGS_TYPE)’ defined but not used [-Wunused-function]
   24 | NAN_METHOD(Open) {
      |            ^~~~
../../nan/nan.h:1568:33: note: in definition of macro ‘NAN_METHOD’
 1568 |     Nan::NAN_METHOD_RETURN_TYPE name(Nan::NAN_METHOD_ARGS_TYPE info)
      |                                 ^~~~
make: *** [binding.target.mk:122: Release/obj.target/binding/src/binding.o] Error 1
make: Leaving directory '/home/israel/Documents/sound-wave-image-generator/node_modules/speaker/build'
gyp ERR! build error 
gyp ERR! stack Error: `make` failed with exit code: 2
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (/home/israel/.nvm/versions/node/v12.18.3/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/build.js:194:23)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:315:20)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:275:12)
gyp ERR! System Linux 5.4.0-42-generic
gyp ERR! command "/home/israel/.nvm/versions/node/v12.18.3/bin/node" "/home/israel/.nvm/versions/node/v12.18.3/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd /home/israel/Documents/sound-wave-image-generator/node_modules/speaker
gyp ERR! node -v v12.18.3
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v5.1.0
gyp ERR! not ok
```

I also ran the command: `locate asoundlib.h` and it gave the following result:

```
israel@israel-Latitude-E7470:~/Documents/sound-wave-image-generator$ locate asound lib.h
/home/israel/.cache/node-gyp/10.19.0/include/node/zlib.h
/home/israel/.cache/node-gyp/12.18.3/include/node/zlib.h
/home/israel/.nvm/versions/node/v12.18.3/include/node/zlib.h
/home/israel/.nvm/versions/node/v9.0.0/include/node/zlib.h
/home/israel/Documents/Israel-Training-Hamsa/sample-form/node_modules/@apollo/client/node_modules/tslib/tslib.html
/home/israel/Documents/Israel-Training-Hamsa/sample-form/node_modules/@apollo/react-common/node_modules/tslib/tslib.html
/home/israel/Documents/Israel-Training-Hamsa/sample-form/node_modules/@apollo/react-components/node_modules/tslib/tslib.html
/home/israel/Documents/Israel-Training-Hamsa/sample-form/node_modules/@apollo/react-hoc/node_modules/tslib/tslib.html
/home/israel/Documents/Israel-Training-Hamsa/sample-form/node_modules/@apollo/react-ssr/node_modules/tslib/tslib.html
/home/israel/Documents/Israel-Training-Hamsa/sample-form/node_modules/@shopify/polaris-tokens/node_modules/tslib/tslib.html
/home/israel/Documents/Israel-Training-Hamsa/sample-form/node_modules/apollo-boost/node_modules/tslib/tslib.html
/home/israel/Documents/Israel-Training-Hamsa/sample-form/node_modules/apollo-cache/node_modules/tslib/tslib.html
/home/israel/Documents/Israel-Training-Hamsa/sample-form/node_modules/apollo-cache-inmemory/node_modules/tslib/tslib.html
/home/israel/Documents/Israel-Training-Hamsa/sample-form/node_modules/apollo-client/node_modules/tslib/tslib.html
/home/israel/Documents/Israel-Training-Hamsa/sample-form/node_modules/react-apollo/node_modules/tslib/tslib.html
/home/israel/Documents/Israel-Training-Hamsa/sample-form/node_modules/tslib/tslib.html
/home/israel/Documents/sample-embedded-app/node_modules/tslib/tslib.html
/home/israel/Documents/sound-wave-image-generator/node_modules/tslib/tslib.html
/home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/Homebrew/Library/Taps/homebrew/homebrew-core/Formula/ecasound.rb
/snap/core/9436/usr/include/reglib/reglib.h
/snap/core/9665/usr/include/reglib/reglib.h
/snap/gnome-3-34-1804/24/usr/include/stdlib.h
/snap/gnome-3-34-1804/24/usr/include/zlib.h
/snap/gnome-3-34-1804/24/usr/include/X11/XKBlib.h
/snap/gnome-3-34-1804/24/usr/include/X11/Xlib.h
/snap/gnome-3-34-1804/24/usr/include/X11/ICE/ICElib.h
/snap/gnome-3-34-1804/24/usr/include/X11/SM/SMlib.h
/snap/gnome-3-34-1804/24/usr/include/c++/6/stdlib.h
/snap/gnome-3-34-1804/24/usr/include/c++/6/tr1/stdlib.h
/snap/gnome-3-34-1804/24/usr/include/cairo/cairo-xlib.h
/snap/gnome-3-34-1804/24/usr/include/dbus-1.0/dbus/dbus-glib.h
/snap/gnome-3-34-1804/24/usr/include/freetype2/freetype/config/ftstdlib.h
/snap/gnome-3-34-1804/24/usr/include/gdk-pixbuf-2.0/gdk-pixbuf-xlib/gdk-pixbuf-xlib.h
/snap/gnome-3-34-1804/24/usr/include/glib-2.0/glib.h
/snap/gnome-3-34-1804/24/usr/include/glib-2.0/glib/gi18n-lib.h
/snap/gnome-3-34-1804/24/usr/include/harfbuzz/hb-glib.h
/snap/gnome-3-34-1804/24/usr/include/libdbusmenu-glib-0.4/libdbusmenu-glib/dbusmenu-glib.h
/snap/gnome-3-34-1804/24/usr/include/linux/ultrasound.h
/snap/gnome-3-34-1804/24/usr/include/rpcsvc/nislib.h
/snap/gnome-3-34-1804/24/usr/include/sound/asound.h
/snap/gnome-3-34-1804/24/usr/include/sound/asound_fm.h
/snap/gnome-3-34-1804/24/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/stdlib.h
/snap/gnome-3-34-1804/24/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libasound.so.2
/snap/gnome-3-34-1804/24/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libasound.so.2.0.0
/snap/gnome-3-34-1804/36/usr/include/stdlib.h
/snap/gnome-3-34-1804/36/usr/include/zlib.h
/snap/gnome-3-34-1804/36/usr/include/X11/XKBlib.h
/snap/gnome-3-34-1804/36/usr/include/X11/Xlib.h
/snap/gnome-3-34-1804/36/usr/include/X11/ICE/ICElib.h
/snap/gnome-3-34-1804/36/usr/include/X11/SM/SMlib.h
/snap/gnome-3-34-1804/36/usr/include/c++/6/stdlib.h
/snap/gnome-3-34-1804/36/usr/include/c++/6/tr1/stdlib.h
/snap/gnome-3-34-1804/36/usr/include/cairo/cairo-xlib.h
/snap/gnome-3-34-1804/36/usr/include/dbus-1.0/dbus/dbus-glib.h
/snap/gnome-3-34-1804/36/usr/include/freetype2/freetype/config/ftstdlib.h
/snap/gnome-3-34-1804/36/usr/include/gdk-pixbuf-2.0/gdk-pixbuf-xlib/gdk-pixbuf-xlib.h
/snap/gnome-3-34-1804/36/usr/include/glib-2.0/glib.h
/snap/gnome-3-34-1804/36/usr/include/glib-2.0/glib/gi18n-lib.h
/snap/gnome-3-34-1804/36/usr/include/harfbuzz/hb-glib.h
/snap/gnome-3-34-1804/36/usr/include/libdbusmenu-glib-0.4/libdbusmenu-glib/dbusmenu-glib.h
/snap/gnome-3-34-1804/36/usr/include/linux/ultrasound.h
/snap/gnome-3-34-1804/36/usr/include/rpcsvc/nislib.h
/snap/gnome-3-34-1804/36/usr/include/sound/asound.h
/snap/gnome-3-34-1804/36/usr/include/sound/asound_fm.h
/snap/gnome-3-34-1804/36/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/stdlib.h
/snap/gnome-3-34-1804/36/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libasound.so.2
/snap/gnome-3-34-1804/36/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libasound.so.2.0.0
/snap/heroku/3962/node_modules/@heroku-cli/color/node_modules/tslib/tslib.html
/snap/heroku/3962/node_modules/@heroku-cli/plugin-apps/node_modules/cli-ux/node_modules/tslib/tslib.html
/snap/heroku/3962/node_modules/@heroku-cli/plugin-apps/node_modules/tslib/tslib.html
/snap/heroku/3962/node_modules/@heroku-cli/plugin-auth/node_modules/tslib/tslib.html
/snap/heroku/3962/node_modules/@heroku-cli/plugin-autocomplete/node_modules/@oclif/config/node_modules/tslib/tslib.html
/snap/heroku/3962/node_modules/@heroku-cli/plugin-buildpacks/node_modules/tslib/tslib.html
/snap/heroku/3962/node_modules/@heroku-cli/plugin-certs/node_modules/tslib/tslib.html
/snap/heroku/3962/node_modules/@heroku-cli/plugin-ci/node_modules/tslib/tslib.html
/snap/heroku/3962/node_modules/@heroku-cli/plugin-config/node_modules/tslib/tslib.html
/snap/heroku/3962/node_modules/@heroku-cli/plugin-git/node_modules/tslib/tslib.html
/snap/heroku/3962/node_modules/@heroku-cli/plugin-local/node_modules/tslib/tslib.html
/snap/heroku/3962/node_modules/@heroku-cli/plugin-pipelines/node_modules/cli-ux/node_modules/tslib/tslib.html
/snap/heroku/3962/node_modules/@heroku-cli/plugin-pipelines/node_modules/tslib/tslib.html
/snap/heroku/3962/node_modules/@heroku-cli/plugin-ps/node_modules/tslib/tslib.html
/snap/heroku/3962/node_modules/@heroku-cli/plugin-run/node_modules/cli-ux/node_modules/tslib/tslib.html
/snap/heroku/3962/node_modules/@heroku-cli/plugin-run/node_modules/tslib/tslib.html
/snap/heroku/3962/node_modules/@heroku-cli/plugin-status/node_modules/tslib/tslib.html
/snap/heroku/3962/node_modules/@heroku-cli/plugin-webhooks/node_modules/cli-ux/node_modules/tslib/tslib.html
/snap/heroku/3962/node_modules/@heroku-cli/plugin-webhooks/node_modules/tslib/tslib.html
/snap/heroku/3962/node_modules/@oclif/color/node_modules/tslib/tslib.html
/snap/heroku/3962/node_modules/@oclif/command/node_modules/tslib/tslib.html
/snap/heroku/3962/node_modules/@oclif/config/node_modules/tslib/tslib.html
/snap/heroku/3962/node_modules/@oclif/parser/node_modules/tslib/tslib.html
/snap/heroku/3962/node_modules/@oclif/plugin-commands/node_modules/cli-ux/node_modules/tslib/tslib.html
/snap/heroku/3962/node_modules/@oclif/plugin-commands/node_modules/tslib/tslib.html
/snap/heroku/3962/node_modules/@oclif/plugin-help/node_modules/tslib/tslib.html
/snap/heroku/3962/node_modules/@oclif/plugin-legacy/node_modules/tslib/tslib.html
/snap/heroku/3962/node_modules/@oclif/plugin-not-found/node_modules/tslib/tslib.html
/snap/heroku/3962/node_modules/@oclif/plugin-plugins/node_modules/cli-ux/node_modules/tslib/tslib.html
/snap/heroku/3962/node_modules/@oclif/plugin-plugins/node_modules/tslib/tslib.html
/snap/heroku/3962/node_modules/@oclif/plugin-update/node_modules/tslib/tslib.html
/snap/heroku/3962/node_modules/@oclif/plugin-warn-if-update-available/node_modules/tslib/tslib.html
/snap/heroku/3962/node_modules/@oclif/plugin-which/node_modules/tslib/tslib.html
/snap/heroku/3962/node_modules/cli-ux/node_modules/tslib/tslib.html
/snap/heroku/3962/node_modules/edit-string/node_modules/tslib/tslib.html
/snap/heroku/3962/node_modules/heroku-cli-util/node_modules/tslib/tslib.html
/snap/heroku/3962/node_modules/rxjs/node_modules/tslib/tslib.html
/snap/heroku/3962/node_modules/tslib/tslib.html
/snap/postman/118/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libasound.so.2
/snap/postman/118/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libasound.so.2.0.0
/snap/postman/118/usr/share/Postman/resources/app/node_modules/tslib/tslib.html
/snap/postman/118/usr/share/doc/libasound2
/snap/postman/118/usr/share/doc/libasound2-data
/snap/postman/118/usr/share/doc/libasound2/NEWS.Debian.gz
/snap/postman/118/usr/share/doc/libasound2/changelog.Debian.gz
/snap/postman/118/usr/share/doc/libasound2/copyright
/snap/postman/118/usr/share/doc/libasound2/examples
/snap/postman/118/usr/share/doc/libasound2/examples/asoundrc.txt.gz
/snap/postman/118/usr/share/doc/libasound2-data/changelog.Debian.gz
/snap/postman/118/usr/share/doc/libasound2-data/copyright
/snap/postman/119/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libasound.so.2
/snap/postman/119/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libasound.so.2.0.0
/snap/postman/119/usr/share/Postman/resources/app/node_modules/tslib/tslib.html
/snap/postman/119/usr/share/doc/libasound2
/snap/postman/119/usr/share/doc/libasound2-data
/snap/postman/119/usr/share/doc/libasound2/NEWS.Debian.gz
/snap/postman/119/usr/share/doc/libasound2/changelog.Debian.gz
/snap/postman/119/usr/share/doc/libasound2/copyright
/snap/postman/119/usr/share/doc/libasound2/examples
/snap/postman/119/usr/share/doc/libasound2/examples/asoundrc.txt.gz
/snap/postman/119/usr/share/doc/libasound2-data/changelog.Debian.gz
/snap/postman/119/usr/share/doc/libasound2-data/copyright
/snap/vlc/1700/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libasound.so.2
/snap/vlc/1700/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libasound.so.2.0.0
/usr/include/asoundlib.h
/usr/include/stdlib.h
/usr/include/alsa/asoundef.h
/usr/include/alsa/asoundlib.h
/usr/include/alsa/sound/asound_fm.h
/usr/include/alsa/sound/uapi/asound_fm.h
/usr/include/c++/9/stdlib.h
/usr/include/c++/9/tr1/stdlib.h
/usr/include/linux/ultrasound.h
/usr/include/reglib/reglib.h
/usr/include/rpcsvc/nislib.h
/usr/include/sound/asound.h
/usr/include/sound/asound_fm.h
/usr/include/sys/asoundlib.h
/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/stdlib.h
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libasound.so
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libasound.so.2
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libasound.so.2.0.0
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/alsa-lib/libasound_module_conf_pulse.so
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/alsa-lib/libasound_module_ctl_arcam_av.so
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/alsa-lib/libasound_module_ctl_oss.so
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/alsa-lib/libasound_module_ctl_pulse.so
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/alsa-lib/libasound_module_pcm_jack.so
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/alsa-lib/libasound_module_pcm_oss.so
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/alsa-lib/libasound_module_pcm_pulse.so
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/alsa-lib/libasound_module_pcm_upmix.so
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/alsa-lib/libasound_module_pcm_usb_stream.so
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/alsa-lib/libasound_module_pcm_vdownmix.so
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/alsa-lib/libasound_module_rate_samplerate.so
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/alsa-lib/libasound_module_rate_samplerate_best.so
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/alsa-lib/libasound_module_rate_samplerate_linear.so
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/alsa-lib/libasound_module_rate_samplerate_medium.so
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/alsa-lib/libasound_module_rate_samplerate_order.so
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/alsa-lib/libasound_module_rate_speexrate.so
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/alsa-lib/libasound_module_rate_speexrate_best.so
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/alsa-lib/libasound_module_rate_speexrate_medium.so
```

Note: it works well on localhost, this only happen when i try to deploy on Heroku. Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Given what [alsa](https://www.npmjs.com/package/alsa) does, it's probably `generate-sound-waveform` that depends on it.

Comment: I checked ```generate-sound-waveform``` dependencies on npm website, but i didn't find it there, unless it depends on a package that depends on it, which probably means i can't escape this package if it's very important in the task im trying to do :((

Comment: I copied your dependencies into an empty project and ran `npm install`; the alsa module doesn't get installed for me (on Windows).

Comment: hmm, may i ask which operating system are you using? npm version and node version also

Comment: I've realized that the package depends on ```av``` package which depends on ```speaker``` package, and ```speaker``` package requires ```alsa``` to be installed. So alsa is already installed on my local environment but it's not installed on heroku, so do you have idea of how to install ```libasound2-dev``` on heroku? @ChrisG

Comment: To install an apt package (e.g. `libasound2-dev`) you need to add the [apt buildback](https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-apt/) specify an `Aptfile` with each apt package in its own line in your case the content would just be `libasound2-dev`

Comment: @TinNguyen so I was able to run the first command ```heroku buildpacks:add --index 1 heroku-community/apt``` and it worked, but i don't know where or how to specify an Aptfile, what command am I supposed to run to specify that?